# Testing with select2 dropdown

Tags: selenium-webdriver, angular

Hi I am pretty new to select a select2 dropdown using Rselenium. (Normal select dropdown is ok but when it comes to AngularJS framework I have been struggling a lot.)

The field I want to click for the dropdown menu is Date Range so I look up in the html code (see picture below) and found

```
class="select2-choice"
```

to be the pointer so I invoke command to click on the dropdown menu

```
webElem <- rd$client$findElement(using = 'xpath',
                         value = '//*[@class="select2-choice"]')
webElem$clickElement()
```

[image]

and then i confirmed the dropdown is active by looking at "select2-drop":

[image]

The value I want to click on is Custom:

```
value="custom"
```

Which is under

```
id="nameRange-3640"
```

so I tried to click on it:

```
webElem <- rd$client$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//select[@id='namedRange-3640']/option[@value='custom']")

webElem$clickElement()
```

However the option "Custom" is not selected, the dropdown menu does not close and no warnings from webdriver? This select2 appears to be linking to a few other class... Can someone shed some light on this? Below is the html related to this dropdown menu.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: select[@id='namedRange-3640']/option[@value='custom']" when use this localor in chrome dev tool how many elements is being selected

Comment: Hi PDHide, there is one element found in chrome dev tool typing in "//select[@id='namedRange-3640']/option[@value='custom']" which is exactly highlighting the last option in the html